# how to fire event on file select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a form as

```
<form  onSubmit="return disableForm(this);" action="upload.php" method="post" name="f" id="wizecho" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button onClick="return disableForm(this),ajaxUpload(this.form,'wizecho_upload.php', '&lt;br&gt;Uploading image please wait.....&lt;br&gt;'); return false;">
        Upload Image
    </button>
</form>
```

It is to upload an image.

Here I need to click on the button to upload the image and I've to use `onClick` event. I want to remove the upload button and as soon as the file is selected at the input, I want to fire the event. How do I do that??

Comment: If you are concerned about selecting the same file twice, @applecrusher has a better solution than the selected answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40581284/1520304

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use the change event on the file input.

```
$("#file").change(function(){
         //submit the form here
 });
```

Comment: and what happens when you submit the form asynchronously, don't navigate away from the page, then attempt to upload the same file again?  This code will only execute once, the second time, selecting the same file will not execute a change event

Comment: @ChristopherThomas' objection is exactly why I'm here, and luckily there is a much-undervoted response below that solves it, years later: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40581284/4526479

Comment: change event doesn't trigger when I select the same file again. Any other way which can work every time?

Comment: @Tᴀʀᴇǫ Mᴀʜᴍᴏᴏᴅ See comment just above yours.

Comment: The fact that the answer doesn't use pure javascript is just wrong

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou And what exactly is wrong with giving a jQuery answer when OP tagged jQuery in his question?

Answer (score 79):

You could subscribe for the onchange event on the input field:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {
    // fire the upload here
};
```

Answer (score 60):

This is an older question that needs a newer answer that will address @Christopher Thomas's concern above in the accept answer's comments. If you don't navigate away from the page and then select the file a second time, you need to clear the value when you click or do a touchstart(for mobile). The below will work even when you navigate away from the page and uses jquery:

```
//the HTML
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />



//the JavaScript

/*resets the value to address navigating away from the page 
and choosing to upload the same file */ 

$('#file').on('click touchstart' , function(){
    $(this).val('');
});


//Trigger now when you have selected any file 
$("#file").change(function(e) {
    //do whatever you want here
});
```

Comment: Is this cross-browser compatible?  Looks like it's just using `val('')`, which doesn't work in most browsers.

Comment: Which browser doesn't it work on that you tried? Try cloning the object with itself it if it is still an issue for you.

Comment: My issue was using `element.setAttribute("value", "")` If you are not using jQuery you need to use `element.value = ""` to get the file element to really clear properly.

Answer (score 5):

vanilla js using es6

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="file"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
 const file = e.target.files[0];
  // todo: use file pointer
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for vue users, solving problem when you upload same file multiple times and @change event is not triggering:

```
 <input
      ref="fileInput"
      type="file"
      @click="onClick"
    />
  methods: {
    onClick() {
       this.$refs.fileInput.value = ''
       // further logic for file...
    }
  }
```

Comment: <input type="file" @change="onFileChange" class="input upload-input" ref="inputFile"/>
self.$refs.inputFile.value = ''

Answer (score 1):

Do whatever you want to do after the file loads successfully.just after the completion of your file processing set the value of file control to blank string.so the .change() will always be called even the file name changes or not. like for example you can do this thing and worked for me like charm

```
  $('#myFile').change(function () {
    LoadFile("myFile");//function to do processing of file.
    $('#myFile').val('');// set the value to empty of myfile control.
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="fusk" type="file" name="upload" style="display: none;"
    onChange=" document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange" class="input upload-input" ref="inputFile"/>

onFileChange(e) {
    //upload file and then delete it from input 
    self.$refs.inputFile.value = ''
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.