# How to get file object to dataURL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How to convert file object to dataURL in javascript?

My HTML code is

```
<input id="FileUpload" type="file" name="files[]" class="filestyle" data-input="false"
    data-buttonText="Add Files" data-badge="false" data-buttonName="btn-primary"onclick="validateFiles() "

    data-url="rest/ses/${eVO.id}/esultFile.json" multiple >
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function validateFiles() {
var prodVisible = $('#caseFileProductionTab').is(':visible');
var fileObj = document.getElementById('caseResultFileUpload');

fileObj.url=""rest/ses/${eVO.id}/esultFile.json?prodVisible="+prodVisible  ;

        }
```

I want to redirect on data-url + extra parameter like prodVisible  on server.  but in javascript i am unable to get value of data-url. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `validateFiles` function you can access your attribute like this:

```
document.getElementById("FileUpload").getAttribute("data-url");
```

Comment: getting proper but How can i redirect at data-url after adding extra parameter ?

Comment: When do you want to redirect? On clicking of the file input or after the file has been uploaded?

Comment: after select file i want to redirect

Comment: You can attach to the `onchange` event instead of `onclick` as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942858/2419531. But don't you want to save the file before redirecting?

Comment: I am redirecting on window.location = fileObjectUrl+productionfile; but not getting value of productionfile on server