# Javascript best way to validate file input if there is content in a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, file, input

I have a pretty speciffic question, I have an input file, every time I add a file a new `li` with the file name is added to an existing `ul`.

I want to create a function that will validate the file input field, If there are `li's` in the `ul.file-list` I want to remove the `required` attribute and if the `ul.file-list` is empty I want to add the `required` `attr` to the file input field.

I thought checking the length of the li's in the ul, if the length is not equal to 0 than remove the require from the file input, the issue is that the event happens when I click the "add file" button and it is before the file is actually added so for example I have no li's in the ul and I click the "add file" button I will get 0, I want to receive the number of li's after the file is added.

This is the file input field html code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">

    <div class="custom-file" id="tz-file">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="tzfile">add file</label>

      <ul class="file-list">

        <li>
          <a href="./uploads/303748891/585943101000100490462no.jpg" target="_blank"> 585943101000100490462no.jpg </a>
          <span class="item-file" id="2018-303748891-21317-0" href="21317/0">remove file</span>
        </li>
      </ul>


      <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="tzfile" name="tzfile" required="">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code I have written:

```
document.onload = whenFileRemoved();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.item-file, input[type="file"]').bind("click", whenFileRemoved);
});

function whenFileRemoved(){

        var isItemInList = $(this).closest('.row').find('.file-list li').length;
        console.log(isItemInList);

        if(isItemInList != 0){
             $(this).closest('.row').find('input[type=file]').prop('required', false);
     }else{
        $(this).closest('.row').find('input[type=file]').prop('required', true);

     };

};
```

any help will be great.

Comment: Did you try subscribing to the `change` event? This sounds to me like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942821/how-to-fire-event-on-file-select

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fire event on file select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942821/how-to-fire-event-on-file-select)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
$('span.item-file, input[type="file"]').bind("click", whenFileRemoved);
```

to this

```
$('span.item-file, input[type="file"]').bind("change", whenFileRemoved);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205957/jquery-difference-between-change-and-click-event-of-checkbox) is some informatrion on difference between `click` and `change` events.

Also note, that if somone will choose the same file for the second time, the `change` event will not trigger (since there was no change to the file input).

But in your case I believe that this is expected behaviour.